# MeteorJS - Watch for server variable change and update the template value

Tags: meteor, reactive-programming

I have a doubt. Not sure if it's possible and didn't find a clear answer about it.

Is it possible to add a "watcher" to a server variable so when the value changes, I can update the view (client side) ?

Let say I have a `var counter = 0` and a Timeout function which updates the counter variable every minute.

I want to update a `<span>{{counter}}</span>` in the client side. I would need to add a "watcher" to this server variable and make it **reactive.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at [Tracker.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/tracker). Put the variable in a Session and have the Tracker "watch" for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to make a collection and store that variable in the collection (even if this means you have a collection with one document).

On server/client common code:

```
Counter = new Mongo.Collection("counter");
```

On client make a helper:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  counter: function () {
    return Counter.findOne();
  }
});
```

On server make sure there is a counter:

```
if (Counter.find().count() === 0) {
  Counter.insert({value: 0});
}
```

Then, on the server increment the counter:

```
Counter.update({}, {$inc: {value: 1}});
```

You can use a similar approach if you want to keep track of multiple counters - just insert multiple counters into the collection and reference them by the `_id` field.

Comment: Thanks stubailo, I've been reading a little more and sounds like the solution. I will mark as answered as soon as my test works.

Comment: Worked! thanks. I've added a  Meteor.bindEnvironment to a callback wrapping the Counter.update to keep it synced.

Comment: Doesn't this needlessly and wastefully persist the collection to the database though?  I have the same issue but I don't want/need to save it to the database.

Answer (score 2):

If your `var counter = 0` is server-side code, it will not go out to the clients.
Any server side data that you want to push to clients should be in a Meteor Collection. Then you use the typical publish and subscribe to send updates to the clients.

If you make `counter` a session variable, i.e. `Session.set('counter', counter++)`, then it will only exist on the client side. Different clients will not have a synchronized value of `counter`