# Meteor: show maintenance page in client side from a server side variable

Tags: meteor

I want to use reactive information on the client side to disable some functionalities while the server is performing an important heavy task.

I tried using a publication but even though the subscription in the client was inside an autorun it was not updating the field. I’m not sure if using a publication is the best option.

Let’s say I have a server variable called “IN_MAINTENANCE” and in the client side I want to load a specific template for the maintenance page, but never allowing the user to change this (The variable should only be defined in the server side).

How can I achieve this without storing anything in the Database?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you have to use the database for it to be a reactive update that applies to all users. You could use a settings variable, but that would require an app restart to take effect. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056429/meteorjs-watch-for-server-variable-change-and-update-the-template-value/28059786#28059786) has code you can repurpose for this.

Comment: I guess that my mistake was to use Meteor.collection instead of saving it in the DB, but saving in the DB is what I am trying to avoid...

Answer (score 0):

I think your first instinct was right in doing a publication. Reacting to a data change is the only way for the server to influence the client. Make sure that your publish and subscribe is working correctly, and then in your autorun function you can take the user (and all users) to the maintenance page.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Meteor brain teaser right? The "without storing anything in the db" is the interesting bit.

Let's say that you have some publication that all clients are getting, whether logged in or not, *and that is expected to return at least one document*:

```
Meteor.publish('default',function(){
  let query = ...
  let options = ...
  return MyCollection.find(query,options);
});
```

You could signal to the client by just returning nothing:

```
Meteor.publish('default',function(){
  if ( IN_MAINTENANCE ) {
    return;
  } else {
    let query = ...
    let options = ...
    return MyCollection.find(query,options);
  }
});
```

Then on the client you just look to see that the subscription is ready but empty and switch layouts based on that.

There are 100 solutions to this puzzle, this is just a particularly hacky one.